# failed to install nghttp2 on centos6.5/6.8

Tags: centos, nghttp2

I download the source from github:https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2.
and install with step :

```
$ autoreconf -i
$ automake
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
$ make
```

Every step is OK,but I can not use it。

nghttp

-bash: nghttp: command not found

But ,I install nghttp2 on **Ubuntu 14.04** successfull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install libev libev-devel zlib zlib-devel openssl openssl-devel git

git clone git@github.com:tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git //or download and unzip
cd nghttp2
autoreconf -i
automake
autoconf
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nghttpx --enable-app
make
sudo make install

/usr/local/bin/{nghttp,nghttpd,nghttpx}
```